# Firebase Authentication error but still authenticating and segueing to next view

Tags: ios, firebase, completionhandler

I'm creating an iOS application that interfaces with [Firebase](http://firebase.com). I have it passing in a dummy userID and password but when invalid credentials are passed in, the application still hits the true completion handler (which leads me to believe that it could be a simple code bug because of my limited Swift knowledge (I'm still learning).

Why is the completion handler returning true still? What can be done to fix this problem?

See the below code.

LoginViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let database = Database.sharedInstance

    @IBOutlet weak var studyID: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userID: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func signInPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if (!studyID.text!.isEmpty && !userID.text!.isEmpty){
            self.database.validate(userID.text!, study:studyID.text!, pass:userID.text!) {
                (value: Bool) in
                if value {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: nil)
                } else {
                    let errorController = UIAlertController(
                        title: "Error",
                        message: "There was an error with authentication.",
                        preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    // set an action button on the alert
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
                        (errorController: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    })
                    // add the action
                    errorController.addAction(okAction)
                    // show the alert to the user with animation

                    self.presentViewController(errorController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            }
        } else {
            let blankController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Error",
                message: "Please fill in all fields.",
                preferredStyle: .Alert)
            // set an action button on the alert
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
                (blankController: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            })
            // add the action
            blankController.addAction(okAction)
            // show the alert to the user with animation

            self.presentViewController(blankController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


}
```

DatabaseHandler.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class Database {

    var firebaseRef = Firebase(url:"https://<UNIQUE>.firebaseio.com")

    class var sharedInstance: Database {
        struct Data {
            static var instance: Database?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Data.token) {
            Data.instance = Database()
        }

        return Data.instance!
    }

    var uid : String!

    var Question1 : String!
    var Question2 : String!
    var Question3 : String!
    var Question4 : String!
    var Score : Int!

    var Question1 : String!
    var Question2 : String!
    var Question3 : String!
    var Question4 : String!
    var Score : Int!


    var validated = false

    func validate(user: String, study: String, pass: String, completionHandler:(result: Bool) -> Void) {

        firebaseRef.authUser(user+"@email.com", password: pass,
                             withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                                if error != nil {
                                    completionHandler(result: false)
                                    return
                                } else {
                                    self.uid = authData.uid
                                    NSLog(authData.uid)
                                }
        })

        let usersRef = Firebase(url: "https://<UNIQUE>.firebaseio.com/users")
        usersRef.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            if let value = snapshot.value.objectForKey("study") as? String { 
                if value == study {
                    completionHandler(result: true)
                    return
                } else {
                    completionHandler(result: false)
                    return
                }
            } else {
                completionHandler(result: false)
                return
            }
        })
    }

    func sendQuestionData(type: String) {
        let ref = Firebase(url:  "https://<UNIQUE>.firebaseio.com/users/" + uid + "/weeks/" + "1" + "/" + type + "/")
        var json = NSDictionary()
        if type == "Condition1" {
            json = ["Question1" : Question1, "Question2" : Question2, "Question3" : Question3,
                        "Question4" : Question4, "Score" : Score]
        } else {
            json = ["Question1" : Question1, "Question2" : Question2, "Question3" : Question3,
                        "Question4" : Question4, "Score" : Score]
        }
        NSLog(String(json))
        ref.setValue(json)
    }

}
```